# Is merging accounts not automated?

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

Earlier I used to have multiple stack exchange accounts:

- **Account C** I wanted for publicly identifiable (in the sense that it had my LinkedIn URL and real photo) and mostly involved StackOverflow contribution.
- Another **account B** which mainly involved academic contributions (cs.stackexhcnage, math.stackexchange) was not publicly identifiable. This was to ensure my employer won't come to know about my academic interest and don't feel that I will leave the job to pursue some academic aspirations. (One of my bosses came to know about my academic aspirations, and he never gave me good appraisals. :\ )
- I had another **account A**  which was created accidentally and I immediately merged it with B after some days as I was using it for academic contributions.

Earlier I wasn't aware that we can hide our accounts from different sites from StackExchange profile page. So I created such multiple different accounts.

If I remember it correct I merged account A with B by following below steps:

1. Logged in to account B on StackOverflow
2. Go to add logins page: `https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/<account B numeric id>`
3. Click `add more logins..` button
4. Login in with google account of account A

However, now I am trying to merge this merged account to account C by following the same steps, but it says the following:

[image]

The link in the popup is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts). It further asks to fill in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) form and StackOverflow team will reach me to confirm the same. I don't remember such manual confirmation happened when merging account A and B. It was all automatic and immediate.

Once I tried to "merge using Google", but it simply refreshed current profile as I was logged into current profile using google only.

When I "logged in using credentials" and trying to "merge using google" account, it simply switched my current login:
[image]

Is automatic immediate merging account no more possible? Is verification by StackOverflow team essential?

Comment: No, it's done at the discretion of a member of staff. Click on the contact link at the bottom of any page (or [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)) and a member of staff'll be pleased to help, though you might need to twiddle your thumbs until monday. Was it different at some time in the past? Maybe, or maybe memory fails.

Comment: I'd recommend keeping the account setup you have now. Hidden communities are actually not as hidden as you think; it's fairly easy to uncover hidden associations through some simple queries.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog example queries? just curious

Comment: Take a look at the various amount of issues that have been reported with it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=hidden+communities